# update object property without rewriting

Tags: javascript, object

I have a method which takes two parameters `key` for property name and `value` for the property value. And when I use it I want to update `data[key]` and add as many values there as I call the method setData. I need not rewrite value with the same `key`, but update it and add a new one, so the final object can look like this:

```
{
    patients:
       formValue: […],
       filtersValue: {}
}
```

current realization:

```
const data = {}

setData(key, value) {
  Object.assign(this.data[key] = {}, value);
}


setData(this.stateName, { firstItemsValue: this.itemsCopy });
setData(this.stateName, { secondItemsValue: this.itemsCopy });
```

Comment: what about `data[key] = value`?

Comment: Add an input and an output example of your method to make it more clear

Comment: @Aprillion `data[key] = value` will rewrite it on every method call

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
setData(key, value) {
  this.data[key] = { ...this.data[key], ...value };
}
```

Comment: @TornikeShavishvili what is the difference between the spread operator and '...'?

Comment: In your case three dots are spread operator. In javascript three dots '...' have basically two meanings, 1. If used in function declaration it defines "rest prameters", please see following doxumentations: [Functions Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) 2. In other cases it is interpreted as spread operator. Please see [Expressions - Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: @TornikeShavishvili yes, I know this, I don't understand your first question

Comment: I think my comment confused you. I meant that spread operator is good to use. I have to be more clear next time.

Comment: technically, this creates a new object merging the previous and new properties instead of the requested `update`, but good enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
const data = {}

setData(key, value) {
  Object.assign(data, {[key]: value});
}
```

BTW, You can simply set the data like:

```
setData(key, value) {
  data[key] = value
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for `Object.assign` over plain bracket notation? (also, `key` in your code will refer to the literal string `key`, not the variable)

Comment: you can change it to { [key] : value } and it should compute the value.

Comment: Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry, what do you mean? `Is there a reason for Object.assign over plain bracket notation?`

Comment: If you don't need to merge objects, or create a new object or something like that, `Object.assign` seems really weird to use over just `data[key] = value` IMO

Comment: oh, yeah, but I have just answered with OP code. updated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned that you want to add as many values as youi call setData. That sounds like a job for array.

You could use follwoing code:

```
function setData(targetObj, propName, valueToAdd){

    if(typeof targetObj[propName] === 'undefined'){
        targetObj[propName] = [];
    }
    if(Array.isArray(targetObj[propName])){
        targetObj[propName].push(valueToAdd);
    }else{
         console.log('property '+propName +' already exists and is not an array');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is to implement a HashMap or a Dictionary.

I'd just do it like so:

```
function setData(key, value) 
{
    if (data[key])
        data[key].push(value)
    else  
        data[key] = [ value ]
}
```

Comment: you are talking about Hashmap/Dictionary (a.k.a. "Object" in JS), but created an Array in your code

Answer (score -1):

Check this solution

```js
const data = {}
var fun = (key, value)=>{

data[key] = value;
}
fun('kk',123);
console.log(data);
```